# PieceWiseLinearVoltageSource in PySpice

Tags: python, pyspice

I was wondering if I could get some help to find out how the PieceWiseLinearVoltageSource implementation in PySpice works, as from what I was able to find about it, I am not able to get it successfully running, as I clearly do something wrong in how I use it and sadly there is not really documentation on the PySpice webpage.

I tried:
circuit.PieceWiseLinearVoltageSource(1, '1', '0',values=[(0, 0), (10@u_ms, 0), (11@u_ms, 5@u_V), (20@u_ms, 5@u_V)],)

But that doesn't work.

From the website there this:
PieceWiseLinearVoltageSource(
circuit,
'pwl1', '1', '0',
values=[(0, 0), (10@u_ms, 0), (11@u_ms, 5@u_V), (20@u_ms, 5@u_V)],
)

So, how would I integrate this into a simulation?

Thank you ahead for any answer!

```
circuit = Circuit('Complete Circuit Diagram')

circuit.PieceWiseLinearVoltageSource(1, '1', '0',values=[(0, 0), (10@u_ms, 0), (11@u_ms, 5@u_V),     (20@u_ms, 5@u_V)],)
circuit.R('Sh1', 'in', out, 10000@u_Ω)
circuit.C(1, 'in', circuit.gnd, 10@u_nF)

NameError: name 'PieceWiseLinearVoltageSource' is not defined
```

Comment: So with this solved, I now run into a problem with how can I read out the current flow across my circuit. Usually I get the current via 
    np.array(analysis["Vinput"])

but, when I replace Vinput with 
    print(np.array(analysis["PieceWiseLinearVoltageSourcepwlvs1"]))

I get

an IndexError

Comment: Currents are not directly accessible in the same way voltages are. I'm way out of my comfort zone here, but try...: circuit.V('probe', 'node_a', 'node_b', 0@u.V)  # (node_a and node_b are the nodes between which you insert the probe) and after running the simulation: current_through_component = np.array(analysis['Vprobe'])  # ( to extract the current through the probe)

Comment: But first insert a Voltage Probe (Zero-Voltage Source) in series with the component you're going for, this doesn't alter the circuits behavior

Comment: Thank you, the simulation works now. I actually already tried to insert a probe voltage source with 0V in parallel to the Original voltage source, because I thought in a real circuit if you want to measure voltage you of course have to use it in parallel, but ofc I want to measure current with the voltage source and not voltage :D

So it works now, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could be because you might need to use a string for the name of the voltage source (first identifier). Also specifying the units of all seconds and voltages could help:

```
circuit.PieceWiseLinearVoltageSource('pwlvs1', '1', '0', values=[(0@u.s, 0@u.V), (10@u.ms, 0@u.V), (11@u.ms, 5@u.V), (20@u.ms, 5@u.V)])
```